# reactjs to create navigation bar

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am just started working with react js for couple of days it throws error like
src\App.js
Line 2:8:  'navbar' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars.this error occurs while i am importing the navbar component into my app.js, i did install eslint package and update my npm version also,i really dontknow what to do .i would really appreciate if u guys provide solution

```
Below code is my app.js:

import React from 'react';
import navbar from"./components/navbar";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
  <div className="App">
    <navbar />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

below is my navbar.js code which i am trying to import in the app.js   
 
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import{MenuItems} from "./MenuItems";
import "./navbar.css";

class navbar extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
     
      <nav className="navbarItems">
        <h1 className="navbar-logo">React<i className="fab fa-react"></i>
        </h1>
        <div className="menu-icon"></div>
        <ul>
          {MenuItems.map((items,index)=>{
             return(
              <li key={index}>
                <a className={MenuItems.cname}href={items.url}>
                {items.title}
                </a></li>
             )
          })}
          
        </ul>
      </nav>
    
    )
  }
}

export default navbar;
```

Comment: User-Defined Component's name in React Must Be Capitalized. Change to "Navbar" in both navbar.js and App.js.

Comment: @gowthamwacky consider putting the solution in an answer and accepting it.